# Google Apis 3.0 OAuth Token on Windows XP

Tags: vb.net, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-client, windows-xp-sp3

Using Google Apis 3.0 with .NET Framework 4.0 my application, that works fine under Windows 7 and 8 doesn't create Token file into the specified DataStore Folder
Here is the Code line
    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(sec, scopes, UserId, CancellationToken.None, New FileDataStore(pathName & "\" & UserId, True)).Result
Everything goes fine, the browser opens to get the user approval, application creates the folder but NOT the necessary Token File inside it
Happens only under Windows XP Sp3.0

Comment: can you share code sample of how you trigger the authentication?

Comment: Thanks @Emily, here is the 'code'

Comment: 'code'
 Try
            scopes.Add(CalendarService.Scope.Calendar)
            Using memStream As New MemoryStream(My.Resources.progResources.client_secrets)
                Dim sec = GoogleClientSecrets.Load(memStream).Secrets
                Dim tokenStore = New FileDataStore(pathName & "\" & UserId, True)
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(sec, scopes, UserId, CancellationToken.None, tokenStore).Result                                             
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ex.Message
        End Try

Comment: scopes.Add(CalendarService.Scope.Calendar)
            Using memStream As New MemoryStream(My.Resources.progResources.client_secrets)
                Dim sec = GoogleClientSecrets.Load(memStream).Secrets
                Dim tokenStore = New FileDataStore(pathName & "\" & UserId, True)
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(sec, scopes, UserId, CancellationToken.None, tokenStore).Result
End Using